# Delete object from mongoDB setting time after 30 days

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB, Nodejs, etc...

I have an Activity collection about my user activities "Add new project", "Update project", "Delete project", etc, but I don't want that activity permanent on my database, I want that to expire in 30 days after created and added do user dashboard, but I don't now how to do...Hope you can help me!
Thank you!

**Here's my Activity Schema:**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let activitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  activity: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Activity', activitySchema);
```

**Here's my server side:**

(this is what send all user activity to dashboard)

```
//Render User Activity

exports.render_user_activity = (req, res) => {
    let userid = req.user._id;

    User.findById(userid)
        .exec((err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            Activity.find({ user: user })
                .exec((err, activities) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    res.send(activities);
            });
      });
};
```

I've read that I can user .createIndex but I don't know how or if it's the best solution..
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for sure use TTL (Time to Live) index in MongoDB.
With this TTL you can remove any document after certain amount of time is expired or at a particular date and time in calendar.

As per your question you want to expire each document after 30 days of creation.
You already have a `created` field just create an index around it.

```
let activitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  .
  .
  .
  .
}, {timestamps: true});

activitySchema.index({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 2592000});
```

30 days = 2592000 seconds

Comment: Yess! Thank you! :D

Comment: what happens if the document was updated, should this reset the expire timer. what if I want to reset the expire timer when the document gets updated or replaced