# How can i delete a product at a specific time in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to delete a product at a specific time how can I go about it,

expired_at doesn't work

Here my database

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    category: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Category',
    },
    owner: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Owner',
    },
    title: String,
    description: String,
    photo: String,
    price: Number,
    stockQuantity: Number,
    reviews: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review' }],
    // expireAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: "5m" }
  },
  {
    toobject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  }
);
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

Please how can I go about this

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52845889

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these

```
 createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      expires: 30
    }
```

create a new product after you've saved this so you'll get the time stamp on the product, this would delete the product in 30 seconds